# C++ standard I/O and signals

Tags: c++, posix

If I call a POSIX function like `read()` that isn't part of the C++ standard library I have to worry about it being interrupted by a signal and handle an `EINTR` return value. If I call a C++ standard library function like `fread()` based on [this documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) there is no mention of `EINTR` so it seems like the standard library hides this from the user. Is my understanding correct and does this hold for all C++ standard library functions?

Update: So what is still not clear from the responses is that is the conclusion that one can't write standard C++ that properly functions on every platform? I'm seeing people mention POSIX behavior that is not part of the standard so this is confusing.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Interrupted-Primitives.html

Answer (score 3):

> If I call a POSIX function like `read()` that isn't part of the C++ standard library I have to worry about it being interrupted by a signal and handle an `EINTR` return value.

And that should not be an issue for your code because:

1. `read` can fail, hence the return value and `errno` must be handled anyway.
2. `read` can do a partial read, so that in blocking mode you have to call `read` in a loop. `errno == EINTR` is just another condition to retry the call in both blocking and non-blocking mode.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about using C++ standard library functions and what is required in that case.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX [covers `fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) as well, which is good since the C and C++ standards say very little about signals to support more than just POSIX.  It says, partially on the `fgetc` page, that `fread` may return early (possibly returning 0), set `ferror`, and set `errno` to `EINTR`.  Of course, if a signal causes a short `read`, there is no way for the C library to detect that and it will simply call `read` again, so you can’t rely on responding to the signal in a timely fashion.  Writing is analogous.

There are very few other operations in the C++ standard library that can produce `EINTR`; unfortunately, POSIX doesn’t cover C++, so there isn’t an established answer for things like [`sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) that aren’t in C.

Comment: Where in the standard is this documented? If I look at the documentation I linked to where does it say that EINTR is possible? In other words is what you're suggesting platform/implementation dependent or required for standard code?

Comment: @MikeSweeney: It’s on the `fgetc` page, to which `fread` defers for errors.  This behavior is required for *POSIX* C implementations (and thus applies to C++ implementations that are built on them), but not other C (ir C++) systems.

Answer (score 0):

`fread()` was originally part of the C standard library, `libc`, defined in `<stdio.h>`. The C++ standard library makes the same `fread()` available through the C library wrapper `<cstdio>`.

`read()` has no such wrapper (perhaps because it would clash with `istream`'s version) but you can still call it using the C library. You're correct that `read()` came from the POSIX specific [extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Header_files) `<unistd.h>` and is not part of the standard library, but it has since been implemented quite broadly and often distributed with `libc`.

You're also correct that `read()` will set `errno` on failure and one of those errors might be `EINTR`. And on the other hand when `fread()` fails, there is [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10125503/3697870) to find out what error occurred, so technically you're also correct that `EINTR` occurrences are hidden from the user in that case. Indeed, how `fread()` handles any platform specific details is up to the implementation. But it would be a stretch to say that this pattern applies to "all C++ standard library functions" - you'd really have to check case by case.

If you want to write "properly functioning" code that runs on every platform, then don't use the POSIX extensions. Stick to `fread()` and friends, and accept the fact that generalisation across platforms means you might not be able to get platform specific details like error numbers. Since the possible errors are platform specific, there's no generic way to know if you should try again.

More details on the differences between `read()` and `fread()` are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584142/what-is-the-difference-between-read-and-fread).

Comment: I specifically said `read()` is not part of the "C++ standard library" and from what I know `fread()` is guaranteed to be available per the C++ standard via `<cstdio>`. My question was about whether when calling `fread()` one has to worry about possibly retrying it because of EINTR. I looked at my libc implementation of `fread` and it retries in the case of EINTR which is in contradiction to some answers here.

Comment: Ah yes, so you did. Sorry I got wrapped up in an edit cycle. Have taken the incorrect assertion out. Hopefully it still answers your question - `fread()` doesn't guarantee anything, including whether EINTR exists or not.